# PlantUML include from URL through a proxy

Tags: visual-studio-code, plantuml

I´m having a diagram in PlantUML (edited in VSCode@Windows 10) and there is a

```
!include https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plantuml-stdlib/C4-PlantUML/master/C4_Deployment.puml
```

in it. Im´m having the Plugin

```
PlantUML
v2.16.0
```

installed and now try to preview it with it. What I´m getting is an error

```
Cannot open URL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plantuml-stdlib/C4-PlantUML/master/C4_Deployment.puml
```

When i curl that address over VSCode Terminal I´m getting results. The VSCode setting

```
Use the proxy support for extensions.
```

is on

> "override"

As I´m working in company environment I specified

```
"plantuml.commandArgs": [
        "-Dhttp_proxy='http://localhost:3128/'",
        "-Dhttps_proxy='http://localhost:3128/'"
        ]
```

in plugin settings (this is correct in my environment)

What else I could try ?

Comment: If you're in India, JOI blocks access to raw.githubusercontent.com: https://www.reddit.com/r/developersIndia/comments/17wd709/jio_is_blocking_rawgithubusercontentcom_how_to/